# Marcar un trozo de código para describirlo

Tags: ios, swift

Quiero hacer una descripción de un trozo de código que va de una linea a otra  dentro de una función. Parecido a como se hace con /** y */ o con /// pero solo para ese trozo de código.

Ejemplo:

```
linea 16
linea 17
linea 18
linea 19 // Quiero hacer una descripción de este bloque
linea 20
linea 21
linea 22
linea 23
linea ...
linea 50
linea 51 // fin de bloque
linea 52
linea 53
```

Comment: Hola Popularfan. No está claro lo que pides. Has mirado la documentacion oficial en cuanto a comentar codigo? Puedes mostrar lo que has intentado y por que te ha fallado?  Mira [ask] y [mcve] para mas info. Un saludo

Comment: Seleccionas todo el trozo que quieres comentar, pulsas CMD + Shift y el 7 y te comenta todas esas lineas, o te las descuenta

Comment: Hola quizás me explique mal, la palabra mas acertada es "describir" un trozo de código al estilo como se hace en swift con /// o con /**  */  o con Mark ( En objective-c pragma mark )

Comment: Si es un bloque de código que necesita un comentario, tal vez debería estar en su propia función... De todas formas, no hay nada que te impida comentar con /** */ el comienzo y fin del bloque.

Answer (score 0):

puedes levantar Marcadores en swift de esta manera:

```
/*
 *  MARK: Example. 
 *  Description: Tags used for forms.
 */
```

Mark es el nombre del marcador.
Description agregas alguna nota indicando la funcionalidad.

Saludos,

Comment: Faltaba poner al principio /** pero solo veo que sirve para describir una funcion es decir cuando pulso Alt + el nombre de la funcion justo despues del marcado */. Lo que queria saber es si se puede hacer lo mismo pero para un trozo de codigo delimitado dentro de una funcion.

Comment: Si quieres agregar parte del código y comentarlos puedes usar esto:

Answer (score 0):

```
**Ejemplo comentario:** 
/*
 *MARK: Old funtion
 *Description: depreciated
 private func newWindows(to name:String)  {

 let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: StoryBoardHelper.mainMain, bundle: nil)
 let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: name)
 self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
 }
 */
```